# Refresh Hibernate cache level2 on webapp side when db updating from batch side

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, caching

I have a webapp application and several batch editing the same database.

WebApp is deployed in Tomcat using the Tomcat Datasource building. This Datasource using hibernate second level cache configuring with her own ehcache.xml file.

Batchs are runging for updating the same database and use their own ehcache configaration ehcache.xml.

So webapp and batch don't share the same Region for Cache.

My problem is when the batch updates the database, my webapp view is not updating. This behaviour is normal because the expiration of entity on cache is not done on webapp side. The view is updating after refresh it.

My Question:
What is the best practice for this concurrency situation ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice solution.You have couple of variants  depending on how much time you can tolerate the cache to be cold and how resilent you can be to invalid cache entries.
Another criteria would be what kind of data are you updating. Is it transactional data (Money ?) or is it something you update once a day and correctness is not critical. I pressume your Batch application is deployed together with your web application. This pressumption is important because you need to be capable of connecting from the batch to your hibernate second level cache in order to send invalidations.

1. Perform the batch and send asynchroneus invalidation messages for the updated entries. There will be a very short window in which your cache will contain stale entries but it should be fine as long as you don't have extremely high requirements for consistency like money handling. The overall performance should be fine.
2. Synchronous invalidation of the affected cache entries with transaction spanning across the cache invalidation and the database update. Performance wise this is suicide :) The transaction here is important in case of failure to persist data to DB you may end up with wrong data in your cache.
3. Shut the caching off for all transactional data that may be affected. The performance of your online part will get affected.
   3A) you can decide to put some warm up logic for the cache once the batch is complete.
   3B
4. Run the batch in a maintenance window. Your online application will go down for that period. You will probably spare development time :)
5. Use your cache as primary data storage and then place a background process synchronizing it with the DB. You may need some amount of replication to ensure no data loss. Some caches provide disk persistence as well.

What happens if you batch and you web application are running separately. That is a problem that can be solved in two ways:

1. You use a cache server like hazelcast or infinispan. Ehcache alone is not a server you need terracota on top to make it a server.
2. Alternativly you keeo the ehcache, then you need to build an interface in your webb app for cache invalidation. For example you can use a queue to send the invalidation messages ad then consume them and process them.

Comment: Thx Alexandar

About my transactionnal Data, it is something i update once a day and often during evening treatements.

My web application is deployed into Tomcat container. And it has her own ehcache.xml to configure Region cache.

For my bathc, there is a trigger based on the crontable to trigger all the night the batch. But it is outside TomCat. it also has her own ehcache.xml on configure her own Region cache.

Comment: @patrickBAK I would hardly call this transactional data if you are updating it onece a day. Is your web application capable of performing updates and how often do these updates occure ? Do you have a SLA in terms of how fast the batch should perform. What is the current execution speed ?

Answer (score 0):

My web application is deployed into Tomcat container. And it has her own ehcache.xml to configure Region cache.

For my bathc, there is a trigger based on the crontable to trigger all the night the batch. But it is outside TomCat. it also has her own ehcache.xml on configure her own Region cache.

Comment: Don't use answer as a way to put more details about question. Update your original question with the details.